# What status code should be sent when a user tries to sign up with a username that already exists?

Tags: rest, http, authentication

I was thinking `403`. From http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html:

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity. If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 404 (Not Found) can be used instead.

Edit: Endpoint - `POST /users`.

Comment: @Madness: Based on that URL, it looks like OP is developing a RESTful API, so error "pages" are not possible, and an error code would be a reasonable way of doing this.

Comment: @Madness: It's good practice to get your error codes right even if you are returning decipherable errors.  It provides an additional affordance for client code.

Comment: @Madness: REST APIs are built around standard HTTP verbs, and expect standard HTTP errors.  You can't just invent new status codes.

Comment: I have seen them with and without the HTTP codes. The rest of the message is really the important part. But here is a breakdown of common uses in major APIs https://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design_what_about_errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal HTTP error code for situations like this is [409 Conflict](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.10):

> The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the resource. This code is only allowed in situations where it is expected that the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request. The response body SHOULD include enough
>   information for the user to recognize the source of the conflict. Ideally, the response entity would include enough information for the user or user agent to fix the problem; however, that might not be possible and is not required.

This should be issued in response to a POST or PUT, typically as part of some sort of RESTful API.  It should include a useful error message in addition to the status, and the error should be appropriately encoded (e.g. with XML or JSON).

Obscure HTTP errors are less useful in front-end web services.  If you are developing a user-facing website, it's preferable to simply deliver an HTML page explaining the problem with a standard 200 OK.

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating a REST API to create accounts, I would expect the request to be something like:

```
POST /accounts HTTP/1.1 

{userid: "someone@example.com", password: "passw0rd!"}
```

In this case, I guess an appropriate response code would be [409 Conflict](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.10) with an error description in the body

```
HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict

{ error: "Account already exists"}
```

Answer (score 0):

That status code is for an HTTP error, not what you need.  Also, it would be very unhelpful as it does not describe the problem at all.

Why not just send:

Username already exists! Please select another.

Comment: You don't know that.  Look at the URL OP is using.  It's quite possible they're developing a RESTful API.

Comment: I'm just trying to answer the questions as posted, without trying to decipher what is actually meant.  But still, a 403 status code for "Username already exists" is inaccurate and unhelpful regardless of the context.

Answer (score 0):

403 is an ok response in my opinion. 409 and 412 are also possible choices.